# How does the problem of quantified modal logic relate to Kripke's model

Tags: modal-logic, kripke-models

Throughout multiple papers and reviews, Kripke's models are viewed as a countertheory to the work of Quine on the three grades of modal involvement. I understand how the modal is set up: I consider a Kripke Modal as a First-Order Model with the addition of worlds and its relationship. I can also conceive how this in general builds a structure for quantified modal logic. However, I cannot see how such a model views a problem like a problem to which Quine usually refers to: 
\begin{align*}
"(\exists x)(\text{nec}(x > 9))"
\end{align*}
or the problem with distinguishing
\begin{align}
"\text{nec}(9 > 5)" \\
"\text{nec(#planets} > 5)"
\end{align}
where the first $9>5$ statement seems true and the second statement seems to be false. Does a Kripke-Model provide a framework for this problem?

Comment: See e.g. [Quantifiers in Modal Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-modal/#QuaModLog) for discussion and biblio as well as [Rigid Designators](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/rigid-designators/#DirRef).

Comment: Thank you! I've read these articles already. The most trouble I had was translating the information to the problem above. The problems described seemed to be somewhat specific to me and not too general

Comment: For Quine, the modal operators acts on sentences and QML is meaningless; thus, $\square \exists x \varphi$ (*de dicto*) is legitimate while $\exists x \square \varphi$ (*de re*) is not. In other terms (for Quine), there is no metaphysical necessity that something is what it is.

Comment: Yes, that's clear. My question refers to the way a Kripke model deals with this problem and how we can apply it to a problem like given in my question

Comment: The issue is : it is necessary that "the number of  planets is nine" ? Probably not. Thus, if we have to manage *de re* modalities(like Kripke do) we have to manage the issue of substitution in modalized contexts in order to avoid the invali inference : $\square (9 > 5), (\text {# planets}=9) \vdash (\square \text {# planets} > 5)$.

Comment: I'm not mastering the topic (alas !) but I think that Kripke's approach is based on the difefrence between a *rigid designator* : $9$ and a *description* : "the number of planets".

Comment: Ok! Does he 'solve' this difference by the use of a valuation function, or is that incorrect? (Trying to put it into respect to his theoretical model)

Comment: You can see some textbook for the details of the semantical machinery; e.g. Nino Cocchiarella & Max Freund, [Modal Logic : An Introduction to Its Syntax and Semantics (2008, OUP)](https://books.google.it/books?id=zLmxqytfLhgC&pg=PA153), **Ch.8 The Semantics of Quantified Modal Logic**. See e.g. page 170 : "the formal analysis of “what exists might not have existed” to be:
$∀x \diamond ¬∃y(x = y)$."